# Cauchy-Schwarz inequality and Frobenius norm

Tags: linear-algebra, general-topology, analysis

Let $L:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^m$ be a linear transformation and let $A=(a_{ij})$ be the $m\times n$ matrix for $L$ with respect to the standard basis.

$$L(h)=\pmatrix{a_{11} & \ldots & a_{1n} \cr & \ddots &  \cr a_{m1} & \ldots & a_{mn} \cr}\pmatrix{h_1 \cr \vdots \cr h_n}=\left( \sum_{j=1}^na_{1j}h_j,\dots ,\sum_{j=1}^na_{mj}h_j\right)^T$$

Show that $\|L(h)\|\le M\|h\|$ for all $h\in\mathbb{R}^n$, with $M=\|A\|_F=\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{j=1}^na_{ij}^2}$, the *Frobenius Norm* of $A$.

---

I know its some application of the triangle inequality or Cauchy-Schwarz inequality but there's so much info here I don't know where to begin!

Answer (score 1):

It is just the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality:
$$
\|Lh\|^2=\sum_{i=1}^m\Bigl|\sum_{j=1}^na_{ij}h_j\Bigr|^2\le\sum_{i=1}^m\Bigl\{\Bigl(\sum_{j=1}^n|a_{ij}|^2\Bigr)\Bigl(\sum_{j=1}^n|h_j|^2\Bigr)\Bigr\}=\Bigl(\sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{j=1}^n|a_{ij}|^2\Bigr)\|h\|^2.
$$